# Randomly blinking screen with Nvidia driver

Tags: xorg, gpu-driver

I have troubles with Nvidia driver. My screen is blinking (on 390, 410 and 415 versions).

Using nouveau is not an option for multiple reasons, but right now with nouveau I'm stuck with wrong resolution.

Seems like a problem with xorg config maybe. But I don't know how to diagnose it and fix it.

Comment: Similar post regarding older drives, might help you [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033425/18-04-nvidia-graphics-screen-flickering](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033425/18-04-nvidia-graphics-screen-flickering)

Comment: I currently face the same/similar issue with nvidia-440. Did you try the suggested solution in the post linked by @Hugo?

Comment: @pehkawn I'm not sure, but I think adding nomodeset to grub config helped.