# Screen problem on ubuntu 18.04 KDE using NVIDIA driver

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics, kde

I recently change my proprietary driver to NVIDIA, and then I got a screen problem that I don't know how to describe but there are some parts of the screen flickering whenever I move something. Please help me.

[image: The problem]

FYI : I am on Ubuntu 18.04, KDE 5.12.9, and my NVIDIA driver version is 390. The problem only occurs when I use the NVIDIA driver, Nouveau driver is doing fine.

What I have tried :

- Changing Tearing prevention("vsync") to Full Screen Repaint
- Adding kwin.sh file to profile.d folder
- Changing Rendering backend to XRender, it works but I want some animation on my desktop

Thanks in advance, Let me know if there is other information I should provide.

Comment: Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185277/screen-tearing-in-linux-with-nvidia-graphics/1185328#1185328) solve your problem?

Comment: @singrium Thank you for your reply, sir. Unfortunately, they didn't work, I have tried adding the command but it didn't work. I also tried using compton, but somehow the problem got worse (more lag and screen tearing). I am not exactly sure though, maybe I added the command in the wrong way because the steps explained didn't match with KDE (and the video too). Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: Hmm, did you check this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033425/18-04-nvidia-graphics-screen-flickering)?

Comment: Also try this: 1) Open Nvidia X Server Settings. 2) Go to OpenGL Setting. 3) Uncheck **Allow Flipping**.  
Source: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BjQDSZUdKXE). Try this first.

Comment: @singrium I just noticed that there is an error when I add the command using crontab, the error is :
**crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.413DOW/crontab":2: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.**

Comment: @singrium Yes I have checked it, but unfortunately it doesn't work too.

Comment: This is strange, because it worked with others. Are you sure you copied the same command? Meanwhile, check my previous comment with the video link, it describes another method to solve flickering problem

Comment: @singrium hmm, my Nvidia X Server Settings doesn't have the **Allow flipping** option.

Comment: I noticed that you're using Nvidia-Driver-390, which is a legacy version, why don't you update to the latest driver? It may solve the problem

Comment: @singrium if you meant the comment by E Falegmane in the youtube comment, I didn't have those options too

Comment: @singrium Ok, I will try updating the driver, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104605/discussion-between-singrium-and-irvinel).